# Specify Dataset in SSRS aggregate function

Tags: reporting-services

I am using an aggregate function to get value of a column based on the value of another column. I ran into this error when including a second data set in my report.

```
=Sum(IIF(FIRST(Fields!LOB.Value, "DataSet1")  = "23",  (CInt(Fields!Cash_Value.Value, "DataSet1")), 0))
```

What i am trying to say is that if the first field has a value of 23 then get the value of the other field where it says 23.

Im getting two errors one is aggregate in aggregate expression and the other is missing aggregate scope. How should i change my expression to get the value i need? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're trying to do some things you can't in SSRS, like nesting aggregate functions.

I think the following should do the trick for you.

```
=IIf(First(Fields!LOB.Value, "DataSet1")  = "23",  Sum(CInt(Fields!Cash_Value.Value), "DataSet1"), 0)
```

All I did was move the `Sum` inside the `IIf`, and rearranged the parens to get this to work. I only tested this with a couple of records, so don't be surprised if you have to play around with it to get it working in your report.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, ill give this a try and report back.